# How to know the files that I have in different branches of GIT?

Tags: git, file, branch

Imagine that I have 2 branches.

In branchA I have files A and B

In branchB I have deleted the file B and added the file C, si I finally have A and C

Which command could I use to know that I have deleted B and created C?

Comment: What do you want to know and in what context? Seems to me that if you do `git log --stat --all` you can see which files were added or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff --name-status branchA branchB
```

This will list the files added, deleted, renamed, or modified along with a one letter code showing whether it was added, deleted, renamed, or modified. It should show something like:

```
D        dir1/B
A        dir2/C
```

Where D means deleted and A means added.

Answer (score 0):

To see the abbreviated stats of each commit you can use:

```
git log --stat -2
```

Change the number for the number of commits that you want to display. In this case it will show the last two commits. Don't forget to checkout to the branch that you want to check first.

Comment: mmm that could work in case i want the different files of 2 commits, but actually i want to compare the different files in two different branches

What is in BranchA and not in BranchB and viceversa